# Ruby on Rails - Devise Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting a strange error with Devise. When I load the homepage it doesn't like this code:

```
<% if signed_in? %><p>Welcome back, 
   <%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %></p><% end %>
```

Because it says:

```
undefined method `encrypt' for #<Class:0x3720300>
```

I did a search for "encrypt" in my app and all it returned was my sessions_helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end
end
```

What does this mean? Do I need to reinstall something?

Comment: Do you have encrypt method in `User` model? As your `signed_in?` method calls `current_user` method where you're using `User.encrypt` that seems to be the problematic part.

Comment: I don't have an encrypt method in my User model. Does Devise generate this sessions helper? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial as your code resembles to it. If thats true then, you need to add a class method `encrypt` in `User` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: I started using his tutorial, but then went with Devise instead. I guess some of my files are left over from doing his tutorial. Not sure how to repair this, might need to just start over clean!

Comment: I knew it that there was some mix-up with Michael Hartl's tutorial and Devise. Well that resolves your question why you were getting error about missing `encrypt` method. What I would recommend is to totally start from scratch using Devise else it will get all mixed up. I would appreciate if you accept the answer.

Comment: I would say remove this helper as you don't need it with devise. Devise incorporate with such methods. You can directly use current_user. Check this link http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/controller-filters-and-helpers

Comment: YES! Deleting that file worked! (For now, I'll continue to test). Thank you, both! :)